# A custom "strcpy" function in c

Tags: c

This method can copy contents from 1 string to another.
My question is how does it stop when it reaches end of string? how does it know when to stop?

```
void strcpy2(char *s, char *t)
{
  while (*s++ = *t++)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stops because `*s` evaluates to 0.

That is, the last character copied was `\0` (the string terminator).

Evaluating to 0 is the way a boolean false is represented in C, so the loop exits when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is equivalent to.

```
void strcpy2(char *s, char *t) {

       while (*t) {
         *s = *t;
          s++;
          t++;
         }
        *s = *t;
     }
```

When the char that t points to is '\0', the while loop will terminate.
Until then, it will copy the char that t is pointing to to the char that s is pointing to, then increment s and t to point to the next char in their arrays.

Answer (score 2):

strings in c are followed by `'\0'` character. This should be the terminating condition for source string. This may be like:

```
void strcpy2(char *s, char *t)
{
  while (*s !='\0')
    {
       *(t) = *(s);
       s++;
       t++;
    }
    *t = '\0';
}
```

Note: suffecient memory should be allocated for `t`, otherwise you'll get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

In C, end of string is marked with NULL terminator, `\0`, i.e. with value = 0.

In C, any non-zero value is considered as true & 0 is false.

When end of string is reached, the while loop sees a `0` in condition & thus, exits.